# Unindexing fields in GCP Datastore, to boost performance (Tuning datastore)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud

GCP Datastore by default indexes all individual fields in your entity. The best practices document published by GCP recommends manually excluding fields that doesn't need an index, [source](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RC1/multi/multi__spring_data_cloud_datastore.html).

I've used @Unindexed annotation to accomplish it in my spring boot application. However, the spring boot app only reads from the datastore. The writes are performed via a standard dataflow template (Datastore to Cloud Storage Text).

The app is still taking 3+ secs to read from datastore. Datastore builds indexes while ingestion so I don't see any point of the above annotation for my usecase.

Please help with **how you excluded indexes on fields**, can't find any GCP documentation. FYI, the application sits in GKE.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Datastore is a schema-less database and all indexing is done based on the writes you do.  Since you are not writing through spring, your annotation isn't doing anything.

Instead you'll want to exclude indexing on the properties you want through your dataflow jobs.  The referenced template (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#gcstexttodatastore) has parameters to transform your entities using Javascript, so you'll be able to modify your entities in the transform functions to match the definitions you have in your spring boot app.

Comment: An example would make things clear. Let me know if you need more data.

Comment: The node.js examples at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial should help get you started.

Comment: By 2022, linked documentation is deprecated.